# Analysis of fields in nested document elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using a document with nested structure in it where the content is analysed in spite of my telling it "not analysed". The document is defined as follows:

```
class SearchDocument(es.DocType)
    # Verblijfsobject specific data
    gebruiksdoel_omschrijving = es.String(index='not_analyzed')
    oppervlakte = es.Integer()
    bouwblok = es.String(index='not_analyzed')
    gebruik = es.String(index='not_analyzed')
    panden = es.String(index='not_analyzed')

    sbi_codes = es.Nested({
        'properties': {
            'sbi_code': es.String(index='not_analyzed'),
            'hcat': es.String(index='not_analyzed'),
            'scat': es.String(index='not_analyzed'),
            'hoofdcategorie': es.String(fields= {'raw': es.String(in dex='not_analyzed')}),
            'subcategorie': es.String(fields={'raw':es.String(index='not_analyzed')}),
            'sub_sub_categorie': es.String(fields= {'raw': es.String(index='not_analyzed')}),
            'bedrijfsnaam': es.String(fields= {'raw': es.String(index='not_analyzed')}),
            'vestigingsnummer': es.String(index='not_analyzed')
        }
})
```

As is clear, it says "not analysed" in the document for most fields. This works OK for the "regular fields". The problem is in the nested structure. There the hoofdcategorie and other fields are indexed for their separate words instead of the unanalysed version.

The structure is filled with the following data:

```
[
  {
    "sbi_code": "74103",
    "sub_sub_categorie": "Interieur- en ruimtelijk ontwerp",
    "vestigingsnummer": "000000002216",
    "bedrijfsnaam": "Flippie Tests",
    "subcategorie": "design",
    "scat": "22279_12_22254_11",
    "hoofdcategorie": "zakelijke dienstverlening",
    "hcat": "22279_12"
  },
  {
    "sbi_code": "9003",
    "sub_sub_categorie": "Schrijven en overige scheppende kunsten",
    "vestigingsnummer": "000000002216",
    "bedrijfsnaam": "Flippie Tests",
    "subcategorie": "kunst",
    "scat": "22281_12_22259_11",
    "hoofdcategorie": "cultuur, sport, recreatie",
    "hcat": "22281_12"
  }
]
```

Now when I retrieve aggregates it has split the hoofdcategorie in 3 different words ("cultuur", "sport", "recreatie"). This is not what I want, but as far as I know I have specified it correctly using the "not analysed" phrase.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: When you insert an object in your index, field `hoofdcategorie ` is passed as a list or string?

Comment: The structure that is passed is shown above. All fields are passed as strings. The problem also manifests itself for the other fields.